# google-maps-react not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-react

I am using this module (https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react) and the map works well in all the major browsers except for IE 11. The error is in ScriptCached.js, Promise is not defined. I looked at the package.json in the google-maps-react module and 'babel-polyfill' is there. Anything I should do to make it work in IE 11? The map doesn't load at all. Any help appreciated!! I have tested in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Edge, and they all work.

Thanks so much.

Comment: `Promise is not defined` - well, you'll need to add a Promise implementation for IE11, because IE is **old**

Comment: you might also want to `require` the 'babel-polyfill' package in your primary application file.

Comment: Thanks for the responses,  I imported the es6-promise (https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) into the primary application and it's now working in IE 11.

Comment: can you please post here how did you import the library ?